# Cause player to take damage in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made two scripts. One that'll keep track of the player's health, health bar and cause the screen to flash when the player is damaged. The other script is meant to be placed on any object I wish to do damage to the player, on contact. My problem is, Nothing seems to be doing any damage to the player.

PlayerHealth.cs:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentHealth;
    public float flashSpeed = 5;
    public Slider healthSlider;
    public Color flashColour = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.1f);
    bool isDead;
    bool damaged;

    private void Awake()
    {
        currentHealth = 100;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        damaged = false;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        damaged = true;
        currentHealth -= amount;
        healthSlider.value = currentHealth;
    }
}
```

AttackPlayer.cs:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class AttackPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;
    public int attackDamage = 10;

    GameObject player;
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;

    float timer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == player)
        {
            Attack();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <=0)
        {
            // TODO: add death script here.
        }
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        timer = 0f;
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        {
            playerHealth.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

The player has a rigidbody2D. The player and damaging objects have Box Collider 2D's on them.

Comment: Are your damaging object has "Is trigger" checked on box collider 2D? There is good table when collision activating https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html, check that your setup meet requirements.

Comment: Also have you debug it? Does OnTriggerEnter2D fires at all and something wrong with rest part of the scripts, or collision does not even activate it?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Inside the OnTriggerEnter2D, try doing if (col.tag == "Player" { Attack(); } instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that the players `Collider` has `isTrigger` enabled.
2. `attackDamage` is public -> set in the inspector. Make sure it is not `0`.

   You could use

   ```
   [Range(1,100)] public int attackDamage = 10;
   ```

   to automatically clamp the value in the inspector.
3. A guess but I'ld say your `Collider` might not be on the GameObject `player` but probably on one of its children => the condition `col.gameObject == player` is not true.

   Instead of `GameObject` references rather compare the `PlayerHealth` (since there is only one) reference like

   ```
   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
   {
       // gets PlayerHealth component on this or any parent object
       var health = col.GetComponentInParent<PlayerHealth>();
       if (health  == playerHealth)
       {
           Attack();
       }
   }
   ```
4. You have

   ```
   private void Update()
   {
       damaged = false;
   }

   public void TakeDamage(int amount)
   {
       damaged = true;
       currentHealth -= amount;
       healthSlider.value = currentHealth;
   }
   ```

   I don't know what else should happen on `TakeDamage` but the value of `damaged` is resetted in `Update` so right after it was set by the `Trigger` because Physics events like `OnTriggerEnter` are executed before `Update` ([see execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)).

---

Hint: Instead of

```
player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
```

you could also use

```
playerHealth = FindObjectOfType<PlayerHealth>();
```

if that component exists only once in your scene.

---

Or to be more flexible (having multiple Players) all you have to do is change your `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `Attack` method to

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    // gets PlayerHealth component on this or any parent object
    var health = col.GetComponentInParent<PlayerHealth>();
    if (health != null)
    {
        Attack(health);
    }
}

void Attack(PlayerHealth health)
{
    timer = 0f;
    if(health.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        health.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
    }
}
```

So you wouldn't need to get the reference before.

Comment: Sadly, right after setting "isTrigger", it started to work. I had separate issues I was able to work through after that. i also used some tips, including the range for health. Thank you.

Comment: @icestorm0806 I wouldn't call it `Sadly` than ;) Glad O could help. Most of the times the reason we know about those things is because everyone made this mistake once ;)